# no resources 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

i am facing this issue while compiling my project today.
i tried following things too 
changed **`buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'`** `compileSdkVersion 26
updated my`android studio` version

but its not working 
thanks in advance
  [image]

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Restart` your IDE

Comment: done it alot times .

Comment: may be bug. Use `buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'` with `compileSdkVersion 27`

Comment: yes , i dont know why its not working .. it works very fine yesterday .. !!

Comment: delete build folder , after that  
Clean-Rebuild-Restart

Answer (score 0):

finally i   fixed this by changing few code in my code as per new buildToolsVersion'26.0.1' .

Comment: `finally i fixed this by changing few code` glad to see you solved. You should share us.

Comment: that changes were only as per new buildtoolversion '26..0.1' for ex. in 25.0.2 i used   "IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);"
 whereas in 26.0.1 it takes "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);"